# Unity Change Sceneview to camera view

Tags: unity, game-design, camera, scene, view

On selecting camera, I get the camera preview.

In Unity, while editing the scene, I wish to switch in such a perspective view that is exactly visible by the main camera.

Is there a short cut to change the view?

Comment: You do know that "camera view", is exactly what is displayed in your Game tab. You could just make both your Scene and game visible at the same time and work with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting the Camera Object and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> seems to do the work in Unity5.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try [GameObject Menu->Align View To Selected.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877383/how-can-i-look-through-my-camera-in-the-scene-view-in-unity3d)

"Select the Camera (GameObject) that you would like to look through while in the Scene view.
Then go to the "GameObject" Menu and select "Align View to Selected." "